# DC/OS package install Web UI & CLI subcommand

Tags: mesosphere, dcos

Anyone knows how to install the package cli command, e.g. "dcos spark", after the package itself was installed via the DCOS web interface?  Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `--cli` option with `dcos package install` as per the [CLI Reference](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/usage/cli/command-reference/).

Comment: It did mention in the documentation.  Should have spent time on Help.  It would be nice to have that automated...